# JAVA FX is open source or not

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am working on a java project and I have to create a new desktop application. The client has stated that we shouldn't be using any open source software. I was planning to use JavaFX with Scene Builder. I am not able to figure out if this will violate what has been stipulated by the client. Can you please help to ascertain whether using Java FX will amount to violating the no open source software stipulation?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not a coding related problem and hence off topic here. Ask it in [opensource.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX is shipped with the Oracle JRE, you should check the license of the Oracle JVM to see if it complies to the wishes of your client. Oracle allows you to ship a complete private copy of a JRE with your application and even includes a [tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) for you to create such self contained applications.

I would like to stipulate that it is very likely that you will not be able to develop any modern software component without using some form of 'open source'.

There are many forms of open source licenses and many of them are commercial friendly, and some are not.

It is wiser to specify ***which* open source licenses** are not acceptable and make sure you stay compliant.

Tools such as Gradle and Artifactory can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Will check up on the type of license!